# Select a column with special characters in TSQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

How to select a column with special characters in T-SQL?

I tried with

```
select Sub-Department from Table1 

select [Sub-Department] from Table1 

select [Sub-Department] from [Table1 ]

select (Sub-Department) from Table1 

select 'Sub-Department' from Table1 

select "Sub-Department" from Table1
```

but still nothing worked

This is SQL in azure data bricks platform which utilizes T-SQL.

SQL:

[image: Check error here]

Comment: Please don't use images for code or data... instead use formatted text - as you will see we can't read the query like that.

Comment: TSQL , i just added those tags if  some one can see in those fields too.

Comment: Oh didn't know that as it is my first question here.

Comment: In future please just tag the one product you are using as T-SQL is different for different products.

Comment: Databricks uses **[Spark SQL](https://databricks.com/glossary/what-is-spark-sql)** which is not the same language as T-SQL. See here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: "Oh didn't know that as it is my first question here." - thats why I'm telling you :) but you haven't updated your question?

Comment: @peterB is right, Databricks use Spark SQL, although you are using Azure, it is NOT T-SQL. Basically, under the hood of data bricks is Spark. Here is the documents for Spark, you should find almost all the answers here
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use backtick to contain "Sub-department", something like this

```
select `Sub-Department` from Table1
```